# activity link tab

Tags: android, android-layout

I would create a tabhost and make sure that you press a tab, it appears an activity with a layout set from xml. How do?

I thought a command like this:

```
tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Factory").setContent(
new MyTabContentFactory(this)).setIndicator("Factory"));
```

Can I load the layout normally in class MyTabContentFactory ?

Comment: set that layout in your MyTabContentFactory class

Answer (score 0):

```java
TabSpec spec3 = tabhost.newTabSpec("Mention");
spec3.setIndicator("Menti", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
spec3.setContent(new Intent().setClass(this,Mention.class));
```